# How to add a anchor point external to an object that is aligned to something internal to an object in adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point, rotate

I have a text field that I would like to rotate around a point 1 inch to the left of the text field, around a point that is aligned exactly to the vertical center of the text field. However, when I open the rotation tool, I am not given the option of aligning the rotation point target to anything except for the anchor points on the path. When I try to create more anchor points, I am only given the option of adding them to the border or interior of the text field. Any guidance would be much appreciation

Answer (score 1):

Select an objet to rotate, Then....

---

With the **Rotate tool...**

- Click where you want the center of rotation.
- Then move away from that point and click-drag to rotate.

Or

- <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>-click to set the center of rotation
- A dialog box will open allowing you to input a specific rotation degree

---

Check the [**help files**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rotating-reflecting-objects.html) for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Scott is the correct way to proceed.

If you need an actual point to click the Rotate tool on- create guides (or even just 2 lines which you can delete later) to intersect on the exact point 1 inch to the left of and centered on the text.

You will have to eyeball the horizontal guide (or line) to center on the text as using the Align panel will center to the bounding box of the text and not the actual text characters themselves.

For the vertical guide (or line) simply line it up with the exact left side of your text and then use the Transform Panel. In the X field at the end of whatever number is already there write **-1 in** to move the line 1 inch to the left.

Then Select your text and with the Rotate Tool just click/drag or Option click and use the dialog box to rotate your text precisely.

[image]

Comment: Hey.. that's not English in your video! Your English is *very good*. I'd never have known reading your answers. `:)`

Comment: Haha- I am embarrassed to say that English is my language of choice (or at least my language of inheritance). The funny letters are just my not-so-good attempt at animation software- :)

Comment: Ahh.. I wondered if it was all just artifacts messing up text in the video, but parts of it kind of look like German maybe. So I took a leap. That explains why your English is so good `:)`

Comment: Mac.. check out iShowU ... one of the better tools I've found for screen recording (I have no affiliation with them) - saves video, open video in Photoshop, save as Gif. Edit along the way if needed.